# Connect RTC while TFT Display is attached via gpio

Tags: gpio, rtc

I have an raspi zero and it is connected with a RB TFT 3,2" Touchscreen (I dont use the Touch function). Is it possible that I connect a rtc even if gpio 1 to 26 is already used by the screen?

Best regards
Vitus

Comment: Yes! (This assumes I²C pins are not in use for other purposes)

Comment: Thank you! What are I2C pins ? I am still beginner with raspi. :)

Comment: I suggest you take [Tour](raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works and how to ask a Question.